# How do I disable a laptop camera

Tags: webcam

I tried a few methods to disable the laptop camera, but none work. Can anyone advise how I can do this in elementary OS?

Answer (score 1):

```
gedit admin:///etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Then add this line:

```
blacklist uvcvideo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable camera in BIOS.

Comment: Thanks, but my bios (HP Omen 17-2020) has no option in BIOS to do this.